# List of all registers to be queried with `r`

Tags: windbg, cpu-registers

I was looking for a way to get the contents of the MXCSR register in WinDbg. Looking up the help for the [`r` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/r--registers-) I found a lot of options. I thought I had covered all registers with the command

```
0:000> rM 0xfe7f
```

However, the MXCSR register was still not included. So I did a full search in WinDbg help, which did not give me any results (sorry for the German screenshot):

[image: No search results]

So I continued my search in the Internet and finally found

```
0:000> r mxcsr
mxcsr=00001f80
```

I am now wondering whether there are other registers that will not be displayed by `rM 0xfe7f` but are available anyways. I am especially interested in user mode and x86 and AMD64 architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at `dbgeng.dll` (version 10.0.20153.1000) and found a few more registers by trying some strings around offset `7DC340`. Based on some of that information, I found the MSDN websites [x64 registers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x64-architecture#registers) and [x86 registers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x86-architecture#registers).

In addition I found

- `brto`, `brfrom`, `exto`, `exfrom`
- The registers zmm0 through zmm15 can be used as `zmm0h`, possibly for the *high* half.
- The registers xmm0/ymm0 through xmm15/ymm15 can be used as `ymm0h` and `ymm0l`, likely for the *high* and *low* half.
- some more which didn't work either because of my CPU model or because I tried it in user mode instead of kernel mode.